# Forcing a brower url update when clicking a route link in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby on rails app with a relative link on the page that has a wildcard subdomain.

For example:

https://username.mydomain.com with a relative link on an a tag:

/checkout

The checkout url should then bring the user to this page:

https://checkout.mydomain.com/username/buy

I have it going to the right visual display and the request parameters read the proper url, however, the url in the browser is listed as

https://username.mydomain.com/checkout

Is there a way to update the url when a user clicks the relative link. It appears it works only some of the time and I have tried turning off turbolinks by putting data-no-turbolinks in the body tag.

Comment: What does your controller look like? Are you rendering the checkout page or redirecting to it?

Comment: I am using: `redirect_to select_buy_url(@event, subdomain: 'checkout')` where select_buy_url is the route for the /buy page

Comment: Can you add the entire controller to the question so we can see the code and maybe figure out what's wrong?